# simulation of a dice roll game, very beginner

Tags: java

```
public class Dice 
{
    int player;
    int computer;

    public static void main (String[]args)
    {

        player = 1 + (int)((Math.random()*7));
        computer = 1 + (int)((Math.random()*7));
        diceRoll();
        System.out.println("You rolled a " + player);
        System.out.println("Computer rolled a " + computer);
        System.out.println("And the winner is" + winner);   

    }

    public static void diceRoll()
    {
        boolean winner = player > computer;

        if (winner)
            System.out.println("You won!");

        if (!winner)
            System.out.println("You lost!");



    }
```

Sorry... this might be stupid question but I am very beginner to java
I am supposed to create a dice roll game. The rule is simple, if computer has larger number than the player, then the computer wins, and if player has larger number, then the player wins. I have to create this by using If statement.. 
But I am getting the error saying that "non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context" and also I got the error saying " cannot find the symbol winner" 
I don't know how to do this.. 
Thank you so much for your help..

Comment: Because you are using your Class global variables (**player** and **computer**) within the **main()** and **diceRoll()** methods which are **static**, those class global variables need to be static as well. Declare your variables: `static int player;` and `static int computer;`

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of problems here, first player, computer are non static variables and you want to access them in a static method (main) so make them static. 
Second declare winner outside of diceRoll() method so that you can use it in main make that static too. 
Third Make the winner a String as you want to hold the winner name.

```
public class Dice {
    static int player;
    static int computer;
    static String winner;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        player = 1 + (int) ((Math.random() * 7));
        computer = 1 + (int) ((Math.random() * 7));
        diceRoll();
        System.out.println("You rolled a " + player);
        System.out.println("Computer rolled a " + computer);
        System.out.println("And the winner is" + winner);

    }

    public static void diceRoll() {

        if(player > computer){
            System.out.println("You won!");
            winner = "Player";
        }else{
            System.out.println("You lost!");
            winner = "Computer";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot refer not static variable of class in main function.
2. 'winner' variable being local to diceroll function, can't be accessed in main.

Modify the code for above two points and it should work.
    public class Dice 
    {
        static int player;
        static int computer;

```
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {   


        player = 1 + (int)((Math.random()*7));
        computer = 1 + (int)((Math.random()*7));
        boolean winner= diceRoll();
        System.out.println("You rolled a " + player);
        System.out.println("Computer rolled a " + computer);
        System.out.println("And the winner is" + winner);   

    }

    public static boolean diceRoll()
    {
      boolean winner = player > computer;

        if (winner)
            System.out.println("You won!");

        if (!winner)
            System.out.println("You lost!");

    return winner;

    }
}
```